# What is the best option to convert my WordPress website to French Language?

Tags: multi-language, language

I have my WordPress website in English language and now my client want to convert that website in the French Language also.

So, how I can clone my website in French Language.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like the Polylang plugin, but that doesn't handle the translation, only the language switch.

The best way to get your site translated is to have a native speaker translate it!

Comment: Okay, thank you for that, I have the speaker with me and then what I have to do? Clone the website to another domain or something else?

Comment: As said below, you install Polylang (ideally working on a copy of your site rather than the live one) then configure it for the languages you need (French, in this case) then replicate the pages (I use a clone plugin) and then edit so the copy is in the new language. There are some easy to follow YouTube vids, if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I would suggest you use the [WPML plugin](https://wpml.org/) on your website. WPML plugin handles most language translations like English to French, French to English, English to Finnish, etc.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that but I want my whole website to convert it to another language. Will the WPML plugin can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend the Polylang plugin. To work with it and learn how to use it, you should work on a test environment, don't play with it on the live site. After you see how it works, you will realize you don't need to clone the entire website or hire an additional domain, the content associated to the other language can live in your same site.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the WPML plugin on your website. WPML plugin handles most language translations.
You can also translate some strings and it’s work in Woocommerce too.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest [Transposh](https://transposh.org) plugin, that will do this for you, it works best if the site has the exact same content in both languages.